# Button in duplicated Mailchimp template breaks on Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email, mailchimp

I've got a cryptic one here. I was told to add a new segment to an existing Mailchimp template and save it as a new template. I have some experience in the horrific act of E-Mail templating, so that part didn't take me long.

All I did was copy another segment of the template and edit it according to my instructions. I didn't manipulate any other part of the template. So I tested it out and lo and behold, Outlook 2016 wouldn't take it. However what it wouldn't take was not the part I added, but the buttons that were there before. The code, which remained unchanged, was as follows:

```
<!-- BUTTON -->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table_btn" style="padding:0px;margin:0px 0px 0px;">
        <tr class="table_btn_btn">
            <td align="left" width="52" style="background-color:#ffdc01;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/959cb501e7f012a45d76a9287/images/b7638f91-ecdf-47e0-8424-a6074b855909.jpg" style="width: 53px;" width="53" alt="b7638f91-ecdf-47e0-8424-a6074b855909.jpg">
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="height:39px;line-height:0px;background-color:#ffdc01;margin:0px;padding:0px;width:auto !important;" mc:edit="btn_col1">
                <a href="http://www.isover.de" target="_blank" style="color:#000 !important;">Mehr erfahren</a>
            </td>
            <td align="right" width="52" style="background-color:#ffdc01;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/959cb501e7f012a45d76a9287/images/82b06cba-dbcc-4c26-8009-65fef3556dc9.jpg" style="width: 53px;" width="53" alt="82b06cba-dbcc-4c26-8009-65fef3556dc9.jpg">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px;">
            <td colspan="3" style="padding:0px;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/959cb501e7f012a45d76a9287/images/3ed7d472-39d4-4def-bc6c-6e431e7713f4.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" alt="3ed7d472-39d4-4def-bc6c-6e431e7713f4.jpg">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!-- /BUTTON -->
```

Now since then, I've tried a couple of things:

- comparing the code to the working template's code in Mailchimp
- comparing the result Outlook code of the working template to that of  the new one
- copying the working template's code into the new one and adding the new segment afterwards
- simply copying the working template's code into the new one

I and a fellow coder actually both intensely tested things for two and a half hours without getting any results - the code of both versions was almost identical. Even by correcting the small things that were not identical (attributes being in a different order, missing alt-tags), we weren't able to fix the issue.

It should be noted that with or without the added segment, the template fell apart in its duplicated state. This seems to us like a Mailchimp issue. Can anyone confirm that? Is there anything we can do? What could be the source of these problems? I'd be very grateful for any help regarding this.

The following images show the working button and the broken one:
[image: Working Image]
[image: Broken Image]

Comment: Outlook 2016 will use VML to display buttons. Did you have that on your HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly no, can't find any instance of that in the working templates. However, I noticed something else: The working templates all have a "last edit" date of about a year ago, could it be that Mailchimp changed the translate algorithm in the meantime and copying the code forces it to be retranslated, resulting in the changes? And leaving the old code doesn't retrigger translation?

Comment: Sorry am not an avid MC user. The broken button is in Outlook 2016? Windows or Mac?

Comment: It's in Outlook 2016, yeah and in Windows :)